# Exchange Web API project works on one pc but not the other?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have a .NET project which uses the Exchange Webservice API to listen for new mails and tasks on a exchange server.

I got a new pc, so i figured that i could just copy/paste the project folder to the new pc and continue my development on the project. But it does not work.

At the moment it's just a console application and when running it on the old pc it works fine. If i put in a breakpoint in the SendNotification method (of the INotificationServicePortType Interface) it invokes when i create new mail or tasks in my Outlook. On the new pc i can compile and run the test application, but it doesn't invoke the breakpoint in the SendNotification method.

I tried writing some code on the new pc to send a simple mail with the Webservice API and that works fine.

I have installed the Exchange Webservice API on both pc's.

What else could i be missing?

Comment: Does the SendNotification method get reached at all on the new PC? Have you got some logging and/or looking at EWS trace?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Did you tried to turn off windows firewall ?

Comment: Have you investigated which permissions are necessary and whether they are present on the new PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions and Firewall are the primary problems to look for.

Step 1 is to simply turn the firewall off completely and see if that changes anything.

If not, Step 2 is to run your application as an administrator (leaving the firewall off).

You might also want to have a gander at your windows event log and see if there are any messages that are coming from your application.  Open it up, run your application, and refresh the event log.

Another potential issue is that a library that was present on your previous machine is not present on your new machine - or it is present, but it is not the same version.

It could also be that autodiscovery of the web service address is broken server side, but your dev machine has the address cached.

There should be a [Test-OutlookWebServices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124509%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) tool that is installed with EWS.  Try that out and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: This is the correct answer, if someone else runs into this problem, but i allready solved this by Fabske comment in OP.